# Visual Studio 2013.2 can't build because IIS is locking an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

My ASP.NET MVC 5 application is using my local IIS (Windows 7) which worked great until I had to start using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package. Because the package has native assemblies they have to be specialty loaded at runtime.

The problem I'm running into though is that after I rebuild the application and access it through the browser IIS loads and locks the native assemblies. If I make the change and rebuild again, Visual Studio fails and says the assemblies are locked by another process, IIS. The only work around I've found is to keep restarting IIS before I build which is unpractical when I may have to rebuild hundreds or thousands of times in a day depending on how many changes I make.

Is there a more proper work around? Like telling Visual Studio not to bother with the native assemblies? Help would be appreciated.

Here's how I'm loading the assemblies:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(X.Mvc.App_Start.SqlServerTypesConfiguration), "LoadAssemblies")]

namespace X.Mvc.App_Start {
    public static class SqlServerTypesConfiguration {
        public static void LoadAssemblies() {
            SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put an `iis_reset` command in your pre-build config. The entire situation though sucks.. no matter what you do your debugging abilities will come to a grinding halt - resetting IIS / an app pool causes the initial load times for your debug session to skyrocket.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! I'll have to live with IIS constantly reloading, but that's fine since it was doing that anyway every time I rebuilt before which was many, many times in a day. Post an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment - my suggestion is to put an `iis_reset` command under the pre-build configuration step of your solution:

[image: Pre-build]

Comment: Yup, I added `iisreset /stop` in the pre-build and `iisreset /start` in the post-build.

Comment: I'd recommend just recycling your application pool in the pre-build event, use the following: `appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name: MyApplicationPool`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of restarting the entire IIS , the particular application pool alone can be restarted. I am using the below script in the post-build event.

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:"YOUR_APPPLICATION_POOL_NAME"
xcopy   "$(OutDir)*"  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\" /Y /S
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:"YOUR_APPPLICATION_POOL_NAME"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to prevent IIS file locking when you do a Build is to use **app_offline.htm**, this tends to be quite efficient:

(*reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-6.0*)

If IIS is pointing at your asp.net core project folder for example, use the variable $(ProjectDir) as shown below

```
Pre-Build
echo "Build in Progress" > "$(ProjectDir)\App_Offline.htm"

Post-Build
del "$(ProjectDir)\App_Offline.htm"
```

*other useful build variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170*

Visual Studio 2022:
[image: Visual Studio 2022 Build Events]